# Virtualbox guest acting as gateway

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Is that possible to use a linux guest virtualbox vm (debian 10 in my case) to act as a gateway ?

The setup : A VBox guest, using VBox NAT virtual nic, has LAN access through VBox host.

Then, a USB network adapter is directly attached to VBox guest (using virtualbox devices options).

This USB adapter is functional and configured to connect to another network (LAN 2). I can ping / ssh from my test box on LAN 2 to VBox guest.

I would like to know if it's possible to set this Vbox guest as a gateway between LAN 2 and LAN 1 ?

Schematics to be more precise :

```
 +----------------------+
 |       LAN 1          |
 +----------+-----------+
            |
            |
+-----------+------------+
|  vbox host / win10     |
|                        |
|    +-------------+     |
|    |             |     |
|    | vbox guest  |     |
|    | debian 10   |     |
|    | (gw)        |     |
|    |             |     |
|    +------+------+     |
|           |            |
+------------------------+
            | usb adapter
            |
  +---------+-----------+
  |       LAN 2         |
  +---------+-----------+
            |
            |
+-----------+------------+
|                        |
|   Physical Linux Box   |
|   (to test the gw)     |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I've done this with VMware Workstation and Hyper-V.  I think it should be possible with VirtualBox.

Comment: You can do it.  See my post here: https://smudj.wordpress.com/2019/01/17/setting-up-an-all-in-one-windows-ad-test-environment-virtualbox-edition/    You'll substitute NAT for your LAN1 and use substitute your USB NIC (LAN 2) for the internal network.  I'd also recommend setting the USB NIC on your host Windows 10 to not get a DHCP IP.  I just tested this with my setup using a Win10 laptop in place of your Linux box

Comment: Does internal network is required for the vm?

Comment: Internal network works if you're only using VMs.  If you're using external systems, use bridged.  If you're using both, you can use bridged, but your USB NIC would need to be plugged in (active) to something (computer, switch, loopback adapter) for it to work.